# Average and sum in one query

Tags: sum, average

I know this is going to sound really stupid, and the solution is probably going to be simple. But here goes.

I have a value of which I need both the average and sum in one statement per month. Or at least the ability in the end to return both in one query. What would be the best way to achieve this? What I currently get is off. I tested by summing the value for the month of August. It gave me **246.10**. When I use AVG I get **1.04**. It doesn't look right. When I take the sum value and divide it by 31 (days in August) I get **7.94**, which looks better. I'm confused.

I know the below query won't work since it's already been grouped by in the inner query. How can I change this, or what would I have to do to achieve what I want in the end, which essentially is:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    DATE,
    VALUETOTAL,
    AVERAGETOTAL
FROM TABLE;
```

I'm using:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    AVG(TOTALVALUE) AS TOTALAVERAGE
FROM (
    SELECT
        ID,
        DATE,
        SUM(VALUE) AS TOTALVALUE
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY
        ID,
        DATE)
GROUP BY ID, DATE;
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want an average over all values or an average over the days? These values will differ if different days have a different number of values. Please provide example data and the expected result

Comment: I added a very simple example in my original post.

Comment: There are two possible results for the average: one is somewhere around `1.0` (ie just the average of all `VOICE_MINUTES` the other is about `4.0` (ie summing up each day and then calcualte the average of these two values). Which one do you want? And please don't post example data as image but as text. Because anybody trying to help you would need to type this all in, instead of just copying it ...

Comment: Sorry about the sample data I posted. We need the average for all VOICE_MINUTES for the month.

Comment: Then you have to do two queries, one that is summing up per ID and DAY and another one which is building the AVG per ID (without grouping of the date)